# Use additional gem in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

does anyone have any idea how to add ruby gems if Gemfile.lock exists?

I’m using an application from an apt package but I want to add my custom gem.

In the Gemfile it says:

```
# Want to extend Zammad with additional gems?
# ZAMMAD USERS: Specify them in Gemfile.local
# (That way, you can customize the Gemfile
# without having your changes overwritten during upgrades.)
```

But if I create the Gemfile.local with my Gem the Application couldn start.

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run bundle install elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the / opt / zammad / Gemfile freeze
by running bundle install --no-deployment.

The list of sources changed
The dependencies in your gem file changed

You have added to the Gemfile:

mySpecialGem
```

I used to be able to do this with bundle install --no-deployment , but when I do that I always get the same message

Answer (score 1):

the gemfile from the original package is
https://github.com/zammad/zammad/blob/stable/Gemfile

in my Gemfile.local is this:

```
gem 'gem_name', git: 'https://github.com/myname/mygem'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the gem as:

```
gem "gem_name", path: "/Users/Matthies/gem_location"
```

Could you post what your Gemfile looks like?